# Could not find an existing managed instance for this object

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin iOS app, it was working properly, but I don't know what I've touched so it started raising this exception when I click on button to move to another view in storyboard:

```
System.Exception: Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x7ffa72c19570 (type: PropertyListViewController). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'Rental.iOS.PropertyListViewController' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_bool_bool (intptr,intptr,bool,bool)
  at UIKit.UIViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition (System.Boolean isAppearing, System.Boolean animated) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:168
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.UpdateContent () [0x001c3] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:271
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.Scrolled (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000e] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:339
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_CGPoint (intptr,intptr,CoreGraphics.CGPoint)
  at UIKit.UIScrollView.set_ContentOffset (CoreGraphics.CGPoint value) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:387
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.UpdateContent () [0x00068] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:247
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.Scrolled (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000e] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:339
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at Rental.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

What can I check in Interface Designer to make sure I am not doing anything wrong?

I added thhis constructor:

```
public partial class PropertyListViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected PropertyListViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }
    ~~~~
}
```

But now I receive this error :

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PropertyListViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c73ad4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011713a21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7a42b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001101b6aea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 679
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001101b72e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001101b761c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001101be062 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 118
    7   Rental.iOS                          0x000000010c0c6f9c xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSendSuper + 220
    8   ???                                 0x0000000130fb7405 0x0 + 5116752901

  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_bool_bool (intptr,intptr,bool,bool)
  at UIKit.UIViewController.BeginAppearanceTransition (System.Boolean isAppearing, System.Boolean animated) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:168
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.UpdateContent () [0x001c3] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:271
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.Scrolled (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000e] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:339
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_CGPoint (intptr,intptr,CoreGraphics.CGPoint)
  at UIKit.UIScrollView.set_ContentOffset (CoreGraphics.CGPoint value) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:387
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.UpdateContent () [0x00068] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:247
  at XLPagerTabStrip.PagerTabStripViewController.Scrolled (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000e] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/XLPagerTabStrip/PagerTabStripViewController.cs:339
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at Rental.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/abd/Programming/Gits/Rental/Rental/Rental/Rental.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Answer (score 4):

> `PropertyListViewController does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument`.

In your `UIViewController` subclass, add an `.ctor` like so:

```
public partial class PropertyListViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected PropertyListViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }
    ~~~~
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check, but I had not this constructor before and it was working properly!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi If you are using this `UIViewController` via a storyboard/xib it is required. If you are creating it in code, it is not needed...

Comment: I added the constructor you mentioned, but now I receive this error :

Comment: -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PropertyListViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a Outlet in Xib. Your view needs to have a file owner. So a you have a reference outlet from view to File Owner